# How to remove application folder name in code igniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^main.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Currently the URLs are showing up as http://www.domain.com/main/home but I would rather have it appear as http://www.domain.com/home. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Should just be these lines (not positive about the first, the second for sure though):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/main/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this near the top of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?main/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I get a internal server error. I added them at top and replaced those lines and both give me an error.

Comment: @DigiJeff Sorry, typo in the rules, `RewriteRle` should be `RewriteRule`

Comment: getting closer. I replaced them with what your post says and now getting a non codeigniter 404 error "not found"

Comment: @DigiJeff you don't want to replace any of the rules you already have, those just need to go right under the `RewriteBase` directive

Comment: @DigiJeff So what's the URL that says 404? Because this doesn't sound like it's a problem with the redirect, if it's redirecting you to a file that doesn't exist, then the original URL with the incorrect "main" added to it is wrong

Comment: It redirects to the right URL but doesn't display the right file. So when I go to domain.com/main/members it redirects to domain.com/members but shows codeigniter 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found.

Comment: @DigiJeff and when you normally goto the right page, `http://domain.com/members` it doesn't give you a 404? If it doesm then you've set something up wrong with code-igniter if you're expecting `/members` to be there but codeigniter is giving you a 404.

Comment: @DigiJeff so if you remove the `/main` which it appears codeigniter won't work without, then you're going to have to setup codeigniter to work without the `/main`

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has built in routes which is helpful in your situtation. In routes.php :

```
   $route['home'] = 'main/home';
```